# ZXing.net: How to access raw bytes (and overcome problem of embedded nulls)?

Tags: zxing, zxing.net

When trying to read a PDF417 barcode that contains embedded NULL characters:

```
// load image and convert to bitmap
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Image.FromFile(@"C:\Sample.png"));

IBarcodeReader reader = new BarcodeReader();
ZXing.Result result = reader.Decode(bmp);

// do something with the result
String decodedString = result.Text;
```

The returned text is cut off when it encounters an embedded `null` character:

> IDUS3*1GORRELL, LIDIA             9991001041         0060150RDBR1992OCT31NNYYUNONE     NONE     2RRT  2011NOV042052OCT308   5RESRETUSAF AMN   E1  I  UNKÿØÿà

What i need is the **RawBytes** of the PDF417 barcode.

Other, hardware, decoders do return the **entire** string (since it is perfectly valid for a string to contain embedded NULL characters).

There is a:

```
Byte[] rawResult = result.RawBytes;
```

But **RawBytes** is always `null` - it doesn't mean what you think it means. It is not the `RawBytes` of the read barcode; it is the raw bytes from a QR code.

How can i get the raw bytes encoded on a PDF417 card?

Comment: Maybe try: `result.getText().getBytes('ISO-8859-1')`

Comment: Core dev describes the problem here https://github.com/zxing/zxing/issues/555#issuecomment-346624207

Comment: *"Hack the code"*. Hmmm, i was really hoping to avoid having to write my own deocder.